# How to stack, stack views in xcode (iOS) so they completely overlap and are both constrained to the bottom?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to make a row of buttons on the bottom of the screen and the buttons are images. I was having aspect ratio issues so a few sites recommended making image views and simply put transparent buttons on top of them. I've placed six image views in a stack view and constrained it to the bottom. I thought it would make sense to put six buttons in another stack view and then also constrain it to the bottom, but it always constrains to the nearest neighbor so now the images are actually on the bottom of the screen, but the transparent buttons are vertically sitting above them. Is it possible to have both constrained to the bottom of the screen so that they completely overlap? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to use the Size Inspector to change the constraints one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Thanks, Sujith Chandran and Neil Hiddink for pointing the way!!)

**Here is my solution:** After selecting the bottom constraint for the stack view that contained the transparent button overlay, I went to the size inspector and changed the "Second Item" to superview, opened second item again and selected bottom, and then set Constant to 0. Eventually I had to change the value of constant to -70 to get the desired position because I previously set the button images to a height of 70.

Answer (score 1):

It is very much possible, from what you have written I assume that your second stackView is pinned to the top of First stackView. Change that constraint to bottom of your superView. This would be enough for your requirement.

Also Instead of using two different stackViews, I would recommend doing this in one single StackView, which will 6 UIViews inside and each UIView will have UIImageView and UIButton inside.